# How to run library instrumented tests on Android 14+ device with minSdk 22

Tags: android

Android 14 doesn't allow installing APKs with targetSdk <23, resulting in the error `INSTALL_FAILED_DEPRECATED_SDK_VERSION`. My library has `minSdk` set to 22 and `targetSdk` is not set (the [`targetSdk` property is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/LibraryBaseFlavor#targetSdk()) for library projects). So `targetSdk` defaults to the `minSdk` when building instrumented tests and fails to run on API 34+ devices.

What is the proper way to handle this, so I can continue to support API 22 as `minSdk` for my library, but still be able to run instrumented tests on API 34+ devices. Setting `targetSdk` to 34 works, but this deprecated property will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Kotlin DSL, adding the following snippet to your library's configuration will change the target SDK version of the test APK, without changing the minimum SDK version of your library.

```
android {
    testOptions {
        targetSdk = 23
    }
}
```